# Are yew.rs hooks sound or unsound?

Tags: rust, unsafe, yew

Yew (a ReactJs alternative for rust) has hooks that mimic those you can find in ReactJs.
I stumbled upon the following getting starter example where there's a counter and a button. If you press the button, the counter goes up by one:

```rust
#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    let counter = use_state(|| 0);
    let onclick = {
        let counter = counter.clone();
        move |_| {
            let value = *counter + 1;
            counter.set(value);
        }
    };

    html! {
        <div>
            <button {onclick}>{ "+1" }</button>
            <p>{ *counter }</p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

(Code found here: https://yew.rs/docs/getting-started/build-a-sample-app)

Now I'm curious about the state/hook mechanic:

- The onclick event handler clones `counter` and mutates it by `counter.set(...)`.
  What's interesting is that `counter` is not declared as mutable.
- Also `counter` got cloned but `.set(...)` somehow mutates the reference to the original `counter` in `html!{...}` so the DOM will be rerendered when `counter` gets updated.

While this is something we want, I can't figure out how this is compatible with rusts "only one mutable reference at a time" and that you shouldn't be able to mutate a variable that's declared as immutable.

Is there something I'm missing or did they implement it an "unsafe" way to feel more ReactJs like?

Comment: This is called [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html). It might use `unsafe` under the hood (I have no idea) but I'm going to assume that care was taken to make the most basic interactivity pattern sound.

Comment: Other abstractions from the standard library do similar stuff but check the mutability promises at runtime or by blocking.

Comment: Sounds like `counter` is basically a `Rc<RefCell<i32>>`, which has exactly the behavior you describe (cloning turns a reference into an owned value without cloning, plus interior mutability). `Rc<RefCell<T>>` and its async cousin `Arc<Mutex<T>>` are very common in Rust.